# Liferay JSF service builder configuration error

Tags: jsf, liferay, liferay-service-builder

Am newbie to Liferay. I have created one JSF portlet and added the service builder to it. Using this link [Generate a Persistence Framework](https://dev.liferay.com/pt/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/using-service-builder-to-generate-a-persistence-fr). After configure a service builder i have generated the source using service builder. But am getting following exception when build service of project.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No entity column exist with column database name guestbookId for entity Guestbook
 [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.service.builder.ServiceBuilder._getEntityColumnByColumnDBName(ServiceBuilder.java:4242)
 [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.service.builder.ServiceBuilder._getColumnLengths(ServiceBuilder.java:3857)
 [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.service.builder.ServiceBuilder._createSQLIndexes(ServiceBuilder.java:3355)
 [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.service.builder.ServiceBuilder.<init>(ServiceBuilder.java:796)
 [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.service.builder.ServiceBuilder.main(ServiceBuilder.java:216)
 [echo]     -Dservice.tpl.spring_xml_session=com/liferay/portal/tools/service/builder/dependencies/spring_xml_session.ftl
 [echo] Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0\portlets\jsfguestbook-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
 [copy] Copied 9 empty directories to 9 empty directories under D:\liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0\portlets\jsfguestbook-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
[javac] Compiling 38 source files to D:\liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0\portlets\jsfguestbook-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
[javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
  [jar] Building jar: D:\liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0\portlets\jsfguestbook-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\lib\jsfguestbook-portlet-service.jar
[delete] Deleting directory D:\liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0\portlets\jsfguestbook-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 8 seconds
```

Also after built the service i have added the code as per article. I got no method is configured for following code.

```
public Guestbook getFirstGuestbookByName(long groupId, String name) throws SystemException {
    Guestbook guestbook = null;

    List<Guestbook> guestbooks = guestbookPersistence.findByName(groupId, name); // This method is not exist.
    if (guestbooks != null && guestbooks.size() > 0) {
        guestbook = guestbooks.get(0);
    }

    return guestbook;
}
```

My service.xml configuration is follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE service-builder PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Service Builder 7.0.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_7_0_0.dtd">
<service-builder package-path="com.liferay.docs.guestbook">
<author>muthuvignesh.k</author>
<namespace>GB</namespace>
<entity name="Guestbook" local-service="true" uuid="true">

    <!-- PK fields -->

    <column name="guestbookId" type="long" primary="true"></column>

    <!-- Group instance -->

    <column name="groupId" type="long"></column>

    <!-- Audit fields -->

    <column name="companyId" type="long"></column>
    <column name="userId" type="long"></column>
    <column name="userName" type="String"></column>
    <column name="createDate" type="Date"></column>
    <column name="modifiedDate" type="Date"></column>
    <column name="name" type="String"></column>
    <finder name="GroupId" return-type="Collection">
        <finder-column name="groupId"></finder-column>
    </finder>
</entity>
<entity name="Entry" local-service="true" uuid="true">

    <!-- PK fields -->

    <column name="entryId" type="long" primary="true"></column>

    <!-- Group instance -->

    <column name="groupId" type="long"></column>

    <!-- Audit fields -->

    <column name="companyId" type="long"></column>
    <column name="userId" type="long"></column>
    <column name="userName" type="String"></column>
    <column name="createDate" type="Date"></column>
    <column name="modifiedDate" type="Date"></column>
    <column name="name" type="String"></column>
    <column name="email" type="String"></column>
    <column name="message" type="String"></column>
    <column name="guestbookId" type="long"></column>
    <finder name="G_G" return-type="Collection">
        <finder-column name="groupId"></finder-column>
        <finder-column name="guestbookId"></finder-column>
    </finder>
</entity>
<exceptions>
    <exception>GuestbookName</exception>
    <exception>EntryName</exception>
    <exception>EntryMessage</exception>
    <exception>EntryEmail</exception>
</exceptions>
```

Since i have using Liferay 7.0 for this. How to overcome this.

Answer (score 2):

I had a same error in 6.2. It seems that the error was in the WEB-INF/sql/indexes.sql file. An index entry was using the field that the service builder could not find (but existed in the service.xml).

I think (but I couldn't verify it) the problem was occurred by an older version of liferay maven plugin (6.2.0-ga1). By deleting the file and upgrading to version 6.2.5, service builder generated a different indexes.sql and the build was successful.

Comment: Thank you so much, yes indexes.sql was the problem.
I just removed index create query from my indexes.sql file of that specific table for which I was getting error. I build again after removing create index query and error gone.
I am using Liferay 7.1 DXP
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### Service Builder

The issue appears to be in your service builder.

1.What stands out the most is your malformed XML.  You need to close the  tag.
 2.Secondly in your Java code you are trying to access a finder that doesn't exist.  The only finder you have defined in your hibernate file is groupId.  It would look something like

```
     return guestbookPersistence.findByGroupId(groupId);
```

3.To create a groupid and name find it would look similar to your entry finder.

```
    <finder name="G_N" return-type="Collection">
        <finder-column name="groupId"></finder-column>
        <finder-column name="name"></finder-column>
    </finder>
```

and your java code

```
return guestbookPersistence.findByG_N(groupId, name);
```

**service.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE service-builder PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Service Builder 7.0.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_7_0_0.dtd">
<service-builder package-path="com.latham.data">
    <author>muthuvignesh.k</author>
    <namespace>GB</namespace>
    <entity name="Guestbook" local-service="true" uuid="true">

        <!-- PK fields -->

        <column name="guestbookId" type="long" primary="true"></column>

        <!-- Group instance -->

        <column name="groupId" type="long"></column>

        <!-- Audit fields -->

        <column name="companyId" type="long"></column>
        <column name="userId" type="long"></column>
        <column name="userName" type="String"></column>
        <column name="createDate" type="Date"></column>
        <column name="modifiedDate" type="Date"></column>
        <column name="name" type="String"></column>
        <finder name="GroupId" return-type="Collection">
            <finder-column name="groupId"></finder-column>
        </finder>
        <finder name="G_N" return-type="Collection">
            <finder-column name="groupId"></finder-column>
            <finder-column name="name"></finder-column>
        </finder>
    </entity>

    <entity name="Entry" local-service="true" uuid="true">

        <!-- PK fields -->

        <column name="entryId" type="long" primary="true"></column>

        <!-- Group instance -->

        <column name="groupId" type="long"></column>

        <!-- Audit fields -->

        <column name="companyId" type="long"></column>
        <column name="userId" type="long"></column>
        <column name="userName" type="String"></column>
        <column name="createDate" type="Date"></column>
        <column name="modifiedDate" type="Date"></column>
        <column name="name" type="String"></column>
        <column name="email" type="String"></column>
        <column name="message" type="String"></column>
        <column name="guestbookId" type="long"></column>
        <finder name="G_G" return-type="Collection">
            <finder-column name="groupId"></finder-column>
            <finder-column name="guestbookId"></finder-column>
        </finder>
    </entity>
    <exceptions>
        <exception>GuestbookName</exception>
        <exception>EntryName</exception>
        <exception>EntryMessage</exception>
        <exception>EntryEmail</exception>
    </exceptions>
</service-builder>
```

> The tutorial you linked to is for Liferay 6.2 but your document definition is  for Liferay 7.  There were some very big changes between 6.2 and 7.  Your code seems to be compatible with both however you should still keep that in mind.